# Can't rely on target typing when chaining methods

Tags: java, generics, java-8, typing

In Java 8, type inference has been extended to [target typing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) which enables to write:

```
Comparator<String> ascending = comparingInt(String::length);
```

without having to use a type witness (`Comparator.<String> comparingInt`). However the last statement below does not compile. Is there a reason? Is there a workaround?

```
Comparator<String> ascending = comparingInt(String::length);                //ok
Comparator<String> descending = ascending.reversed();                       //ok
Comparator<String> descending = reverseOrder(comparingInt(String::length)); //ok
Comparator<String> descending = Comparator.<String>comparingInt(String::length)
                                                  .reversed();              //ok
Comparator<String> descending = comparingInt(String::length).reversed();    //error
```

Comment: What version? This works for me in JDK 8 build b129.

Comment: For me it does not work on Netbeans 8.0 Beta with JDK 8 build b124.

Comment: @MattEckert b128 - will upgrade now to see if that is the issue. The [only change I see between 128/129](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/7534523b4174) apparently did not affect the `comparingInt` method...

Comment: @MattEckert Confirmed. That's weird.

Comment: This question is about a bug in a non-released version of a product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is fixed with build 129 (but appears until build 128).