# What kind of List<E> does Collectors.toList() return?

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, collectors

I am reading [State of the Lambda: Libraries Edition](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-libraries-final.html), and am being surprised by one statement:

Under the section **Streams**, there is the following:

```
List<Shape> blue = shapes.stream()
                         .filter(s -> s.getColor() == BLUE)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The document does not state what `shapes` actually is, and I do not know if it even matters.

What confuses me is the following: What kind of concrete `List` does this block of code return?

- It assigns the variable to a `List<Shape>`, which is completely fine.
- `stream()` nor `filter()` decide what kind of list to use.
- `Collectors.toList()` neither specifies the concrete type of `List`.

So, what **concrete** type (subclass) of `List` is being used here? Are there any guarantees?

Comment: Since the `toUnmodifiableList()` method was added in Java 10, it would seem that the mutability of `toList()` could now be guaranteed.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

> So, what concrete type (subclass) of List is being used here? Are there any guarantees?

If you look at the documentation of [`Collectors#toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()), it states that - *"There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned"*. If you want a particular implementation to be returned, you can use [`Collectors#toCollection(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection(java.util.function.Supplier)) instead.

```
Supplier<List<Shape>> supplier = () -> new LinkedList<Shape>();

List<Shape> blue = shapes.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getColor() == BLUE)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
```

And from the lambda, you can return whatever implementation you want of `List<Shape>`.

**Update**:

Or, you can even use method reference:

```
List<Shape> blue = shapes.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getColor() == BLUE)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Comment: You know, you could write that Supplier as a lambda :)

Comment: Would `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList<Shape>::new))` also work?

Comment: @skiwi No. It doesn't work. Type inference doesn't work with this.

Comment: `Collectors.toCollection((Supplier<List<Shape>>) LinkedList::new)` this will work also :)

Comment: @skiwi Or even better with explicit type argument: `Collectors.<Shape, List<Shape>>toCollection(LinkedList<Shape>::new)`

Comment: @RohitJain Perhaps `Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList<Shape>::new` works now with Java 8 b129 build, as some type interference has been improved. I don't know exactly how to try it myself though and Netbeans 8.0 doesn't support the improved type interference yet it seems (on an older testcase -> See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751830/cant-rely-on-target-typing-when-chaining-methods)

Comment: @skiwi I see. I haven't yet got the new build on my machine. Perhaps, I would download it today.

Comment: @skiwi @RohitJain Type inference is better than you think: you don't need to provide any explicit type information apart from the target type. So you can just write `List<Shape> shapeList = ...collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));`

Comment: @MauriceNaftalin It isn't compiling. I've currently `b108` on my machine. Has it been improved in later build? Of course I will download the latest build, but that will take time.

Comment: @MauriceNaftalin Yes, seems like the issue with eclipse. It compiles on command line, on `b129`.

Comment: Too bad you can't use toCollection() if you want it to create an ImmutableList... you have to write a whooooole new collector.

Comment: @Trejkaz You can use `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new), Collections::unmodifiableList))`

Comment: @panos unmodifiableList is a "Claytons immutable", but you end up writing your own collector if you want an actually-immutable collection, e.g. one of Guava's. Thinking about it a bit, though, the real shame is that toList() doesn't return an immutable list in the first place.

Comment: @Trejkaz Agree, toList should have returned an immutable in the first place, but oh well, it didn't. We hope to change this at some point. Also, what is a "Claytons immutable"?

Comment: @StuartMarks a "Claytons X" is "an X you have when you're not having an X", in reference to "the drink you have when you're not having a drink". The implication is that `Collections.unmodifiableList()` doesn't make an immutable list, because someone has a reference to the list it's wrapping and can mutate that. OTOH, the method could have created an immutable copy.

Comment: @Trejkaz Ha, ok, thanks. That reference doesn't seem to have made it to the USA. I was looking all over for "Claytons" with respect to immutability and data structures and I couldn't find anything. :-)

Comment: @Trejkaz if you have an unmodifiable list but the *only* reference to the wrapped list is the `Collections.unModifiableList` wrapper itself, does that make the list immutable?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException possibly, but if my code receives an instance of that, it has no way to know for sure, so I have to treat it as potentially mutable anyway. :(

Comment: @Trejkaz with recent versions, `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), List::copyOf))` will give you a truly immutable list (but you have to cope with the no-`null` policy). Any receiver can simply call `myCopy = List.copyOf(inputList);` to be sure to have a truly immutable list, as that method will do nothing if the list is already immutable. I suppose, for Guava, a similar thing exists.

Comment: works flawlessly

Answer (score 11):

Navigating through Netbeans (Ctrl + Click), I landed in this code. It seems to be using an ArrayList as Supplier.

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_ID);
}
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that this is just one potential implementation of the API. :)

Comment: @Trejkaz Correct. In fact we are seriously considering changing the implementation at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, but the concrete type is non-generic as indeed all types are non-generic at runtime.

> So, what concrete type (subclass) of List is being used here? Are there any guarantees?

I don't think so, but ArrayList or LinkedList seem likely.