# An elegant way to specify initial capacity of Collector in java stream api

Tags: java-8, collectors

I've tried to find a good way to set up initial capacity of collector in java stream api. The simplest example is there:

```
data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I just want to pass an int with size of list into collector in order not to resize internal array. The first intention is to do it in such way:

```
data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList(data.size()));
```

But unfortunately toList isn't overloaded to work with parameter. I found one solution but it smells:

```
 data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(data.size())));
```

Is there any way to express it simplier?

Comment: Why do you think this is a smelly solution?

Comment: Because i definitely know that i want to collect the data to list but i need to use toCollection method and then specify more concrete type, also there's unnecessary lamblda expression...

Comment: `toList()` [doesn't specify the list it returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912314/what-kind-of-liste-does-collectors-tolist-return). Why do you assume it is ArrayList, or that the list returned understand a concept of "initial capacity"? (Yes, it currently is an `ArrayList`, but this is an implementation detail, and not all lists have an initial capacity).

Comment: Good point. I also thought about it.I just think that ArrayList is used overwhelmingly and there should be more simple way to express the same. Do you know any?

Comment: What is complicated in the given solution? It's "just" one lambda, which body invokes a constructor. You can't use a convenient method-reference `ArrayList::new` since you need to pass the initial capacity... Make your own method returning the `Supplier<List<T>>` if you find the number of closing parenthesis too much.

Comment: I don't think it's very complex. But usually stream api looks much more gracefully. So i asked here in order not to miss something.

Answer (score 4):

I'd take your inelegant

```
Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(data.size()))
```

and wrap it in a static method

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList(int size) {
    return Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<T>(size));
}
```

then call it (with a static import)

```
stream.collect(toList(size))
```

!inelegant?

edit (This does make it an **ArrayList**) is this bad?

Comment: I dont think its bad, the reason being you are telling the Initial Capacity when creating the ArrayList so its predictable

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any straightforward way in the API to ensure the capacity of the mutable container used under the hood to collect the data. I may guess that *at least* one of the many reasons is the support for parallelism by calling `parallelStream()`.

So - if your data is processed in parallel there is no much sense to give initial capacity even if you know that the underlying container (e.g. `ArrayList`) supports capacity. Multiple containers will be created by different threads and later combined and the capacity will at least harm the overall performance.

If you want to be truly specific and elegant you may also try to implement your own collector. It is not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>(100)))
```

```
data.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>(100)), Collections::unmodifiableSet))
```