# Java 8 stream API, how to collect List to Object with several List fields

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to get one Object with List<> fields from list of objects with no List<> fields.

This is my code:

```
public class ObjectDTO {
    private List<String> ids;
    private List<Date> times;
    private List<String> names;
    private List<String> details;

public class ObjectDTOHelper {
        private String id;
        private Date time;
        private String name;
        private String detail;
}
```

I supply `List<ObjectDTOHelper>` as input and want to get output just an object of `ObjectDTO`.

Which I can solve with multiple independent stream functions:

```
List<ObjectDTOHelper> helpers; //about 1000 elements

List<String> ids= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.id).collect(toList());
List<Date> times= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.time).collect(toList());
List<String> names= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.name).collect(toList());
List<String> details= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.detail).collect(toList());

new ObjectDTO(ids, times, name, detail)
```

Which I think is not the best solution, because I need do that more 100_000 times)

Can you help solve this more optimally?

Comment: If `ObjectDTO` must be constructed with all 4 lists (as opposed to adding elements incrementally) then this is pretty much the best you can do.

Comment: What is unclear in the question is that from *about 1000 elements*, how do end up with *need do that more 100_000 times*? The complexity of the current solution is `O(n)` as well, an optimization over which could have been a single iteration altogether. In terms of the best solution, what's not efficient is storing those many `List<T> fields` within an object.

Comment: I agree with you, but that decided "by design" and I'm just looking for better solution.
maybe I can still change the structure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible optimization to add to what you've done already is to preallocate the known exact amount of memory needed for all your lists:

```
List<ObjectDTOHelper> helpers = ...; //about 1000 elements
int size = helpers.size();

List<String> ids= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.id).collect(toCollection(()->new ArrayList<>(size)));
List<Date> times= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.time).collect(toCollection(()->new ArrayList<>(size)));
List<String> names= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.name).collect(toCollection(()->new ArrayList<>(size)));
List<String> details= helpers.stream().map(h -> h.detail).collect(toCollection(()->new ArrayList<>(size)));

new ObjectDTO(ids, times, name, detail)
```

If you have too many such fields, you can create your own Collector to pass to collect().

Comment: IMHO, that just complicated the existing solution

Comment: @nullpointer I agree it's more complicated, but the OP was specifically asking for something more optimized that what they had. They can measure the performance difference (using e.g. JMH) and decide for themselves whether it's worth the reduced readability.

Comment: Okay on that note, I am curious to know how is this solution efficient to that in the question? Any documents around that.

Comment: @nullpointer it just avoids resizing of the arrays used internally by the ArrayLists. But as I said, the overhead should be measured. Also see related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069206/an-elegant-way-to-specify-initial-capacity-of-collector-in-java-stream-api

Comment: Thank you! it really improved the situation a little) according to my measurements:
with size:
`1000  avgt    5   3245.702 ± 120.881  ms/op`
`10000  avgt    5  29253.296 ± 646.855  ms/op`
without size
`1000  avgt    5   3323.091 ±  451.716  ms/op`
`10000  avgt    5  31517.425 ± 3185.305  ms/op`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your fields from `ObjectDTO` is initialized like:

```
public class ObjectDTO {
    private List<String> ids = new LinkedList<>();
    ...
}
```

**Update:** See [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java)

You can fill it using `IntStream`

```
ObjectDTO objectDTO = new ObjectDTO();

IntStream.range(0, helpers.size())
    .forEach(i -> {
        objectDTO.getIds().add(helpers.get(i).getId());
        objectDTO.getTimes().add(helpers.get(i).getTime());
        objectDTO.getNames().add(helpers.get(i).getName());
        objectDTO.getDetails().add(helpers.get(i).getDetail());
     });
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems better solution, but after a few tests, I get the same performance( while I will test it

Comment: There is no need for IntStream... just stream the `helpers` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one CPU/thread your solution is as efficient as it gets in terms of complexity (O(n)) yet it probably has uncessary overhead due to the independent lambdas.

Would it make sense to have an operation to add a helper a a time to `ObjectDTO`:

```
class ObjectDTO {
  private List<String> ids;
  private List<Date> times;
  private List<String> names;
  private List<String> details;
  //...
  public void add(ObjectDTOHelper helper) {
      ids.add(helper.id)
      times.add(helper.time);
      names.add(helper.name);
      details.add(helper.detail);
  }
  //...
  public void addAll(Collection<? extends ObjectDTOHelper> helpers) {
     helpers.stream().forEach(this::add);
  }
  //...
}
```

If `ObjectDTO` is mean to be a constant class (no modifications after creation allowed), you could simply change those method to `private` and use `addAll` within a public constructor that accepts the helper collection.

Also you could take the opportunity to size the list based on the expected and known number of helpers bits that you are going to add to each.

```
class ObjectDTO {
  // ...
  public ObjectDTO(Collection<? extends ObjectDTOHelper> helpers) {
     int size = helpers.size();

     ids = new ArrayList<>(size);
     names = new ArrayList<>(size);
     // ...
     addAll(helpers);
  }
```

Also always use `ArrayList` and never `LinkedList`... I think the only case that linked perform better than array is if you are going to do repetitive insertions in the middle of a large list and that is not your case.