# How to declare a variable according to an unknown List type of the input variable in Java?

Tags: java, declare, variable-types

How to declare a variable according to an **unknown List type** of the input variable in Java?

For example::

You are given arr1, you need to (shallow) copy from arr1 to arr2. But you don't know what type of list arr1 is.

This is the code that I use, if I want to declare arr2, I have to go through all possible cases of types of List.

```java
  static List<Object> funcOri(List<Object> arr1, List<Object> arr2) {
    if (arr1 instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
      arr2 = new ArrayList<Object>(arr1);
    } else if (arr1 instanceof LinkedList<?>) {
      arr2 = new LinkedList<Object>(arr1);
    } else if (...) {
      ;
    }
    return arr2;
  }
```

Is there a simpler way to declare arr2 according to the type of arr1 is?

Maybe something that simply looks like::

```java
  static List<Object> funcWanted(List<Object> arr1, List<Object> arr2) {
    arr2 = new XXXList<Object>(arr1); // where XXXList is base on the type of list the arr1 is
    return arr2;
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to re-create `arr2 = new ArrayList<Object>(arr1)`, as it's already ArrayList.

Comment: Usually the exact list type of arr1 is irrelevant. If you need a copy of arr1, the decision on the actual list type of arr2 should be based on what you are going to do with arr2, I.e. if you are going to insert items at arbitrary positions, a LinkedLisr could be better. But in most cases an ArrayList is good enough.

Comment: If you _really_ need to provide the same class of the copy object, it could be done using `clone()` method or reflection to create an instance of the original list: `public static <T> List<T> funcOri(List<T> original) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(original);
    List<T> copy = original.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    copy.addAll(original);
    return copy;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to create a new instance of arr1's class using reflections.

```
public class ListClone {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("abc");

        List<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
        ll.add("123");

        List<String> alc = funcOri(al);
        List<String> llc = funcOri(ll);

        System.out.println(alc.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(llc.getClass().getSimpleName());

        alc.add("def");
        llc.add("456");

        System.out.println(al);
        System.out.println(alc);

        System.out.println(ll);
        System.out.println(llc);
    }

    static <T> List<T> funcOri(List<T> arr1) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Constructor<? extends List> constructor = arr1.getClass().getConstructor(Collection.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        return constructor.newInstance(arr1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ArrayList
LinkedList
[abc]
[abc, def]
[123]
[123, 456]
```

**Edit**

This assumes that the list type of arr1 has a constructor to take a Collection. It's of course entirely possible that there are List implementations that don't. A slightly safer solution might be to go for a default constructor and use List.addAll() to copy the contents but we can still not be certain that all List implementations have a default constructor. It will then throw NoSuchMethodException.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am completely misunderstanding your problem, this is what you need (Java 8)

```
public class ListCopyDemo {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<String> original = new ArrayList<>();
        original.add("Hello World!");
        original.add("Welcome to Java");
        
        List<?> copy = ListCopyDemo.funcOri(original); // should return a copy of the original
    }
    
    public static List<Object> funcOri(List<?> arr1) {
        return arr1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

If you were to change `original` List type to `List<Integer>` or `LinkedList<String>`, the `funcOri` will work the same.

Comment: This implementation does not guarantee that `funcOri` returns exactly the same implementation of the list as in the input `arr1`: [What kind of list does collectors.toList() return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912314/what-kind-of-liste-does-collectors-tolist-return)

Comment: This is not what I want. The return value is an ArrayList some how.
I tried the following::
```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("abc");

    List<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
    ll.add("123");

    List<Object> alc = funcOri(al);
    List<Object> llc = funcOri(ll);

    System.out.println(al.getClass());
    System.out.println(ll.getClass());
    System.out.println(alc.getClass());
    System.out.println(llc.getClass());

  }
```