# How to create a default list using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object Shop as below. In the main function, I am trying to process a list. If the result of it is an empty list, then I am creating a default list and then processing it further. I am not sure how to create a default list and then further process it, together, using java 8 streams.
In section 1, I am processing a list. In section 2, I am creating a default list of section 1 returns empty list. And in section 3, I am further processing the result of section 1 and section 2.

```
class Shop {
    String name;
    String value;

    public Shop(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}


class Product {
    List<Shop> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Shop> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Shop> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shop s1 = new Shop("zip", "32684");
        Shop s2 = new Shop("loc", "abc");
        Shop s3 = new Shop("zip", "32684");
        Shop s4 = new Shop("brand", "lemom");

        List<Shop> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        list.add(s4);

        Product p = new Product();
        p.setList(list);

        List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
        attributes.add("zip");
        attributes.add("loc");
        attributes.add("brand");
        attributes.add("price");


        //How can I create a default list (section 2) if section 1 returns empty list. And then combine section 1 ,2 and 3 togethr using Java 8 Streams
         for (String attribute : attributes) {
            //section 1
            List<Shop> values = p.getList().stream()
                    .filter(shop -> attribute.equals(shop.getName()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            //section 2
            if (values.isEmpty()) {
                values.add(new Shop("zip", "3728392"));
            }

            //section 3
            List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Shop shop : values) {
                list3.add(shop.getValue());
            }
            String result = String.join(",", list3);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not call `add` method on a list returned by `Collectors.toList()` as the javadoc states -> _There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned..._. As of now, `toList` uses `ArrayList::new`, but it could change as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912314/what-kind-of-liste-does-collectors-tolist-return#comment81881048_21913148). So better to use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`

Comment: Perhaps you should post what the expected result is supposed to be.  Make certain it is a complete example with different names, attributes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String a = p.getList().stream()
              .filter(shop -> attribute.equals(shop.getName()))
              .map(Shop::getValue)
              .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.joining(","), 
                                     str -> str.isEmpty() ? "3728392" : str));
```

`.map()` converts your Object `shop` to String `shop.getValue()` using double colon operator of Java -- which is your section 3.

The custom `.collect()` collects all the values from the previous operation and converts them to a comma separated string. If the resultant string is empty, it returns a single value -- which is your section 2.

Output:

```
32684,32684
abc
lemom
3728392
```